# エックスサーバーでphpファイルをhtml で読み込むたいです。

Tags: php, html

エックスサーバーにphpファイルをhtmlで読み込ませたい時はどうすればいいんですか？インフォパネルからpublic htmlにindex.html のファイルをアップロードしたのですが、php ファイルをどこにアップロードしていいのか、わからないので教えてください。構造は以下の通りです。これらをpublic html に入れればいいんですか？

```
bbs18(755)/┬admin(755)/┬admin.php(644) 
│ ├abon.php(644)
│ ├cap.php(644)
│ ├deleboard.php(644)
│ ├deny.php(644)
│ ├edit.php(644)
│ ├hostlog.php(644)
│ ├image.php(644)
│ ├main.php(644)
│ ├makeboard.php(644)
│ ├menu.php(644)
│ ├passcheck.php(644)
│ ├setboard.php(644)
│ ├setboard2.php(644)
│ ├threadm.php(644)
│ ├vip.php(644)
│ ├main.css(644)
│ ├menu.css(644)
│ └passfile.cgi(666)
│
├test(755)/ ┬bbs.php(644)
│ ├bbs2.php(644)
│ ├read.php(644)
│ ├make_html.php(644)
│ ├make_work.php(644)
│ ├new_thread.php(644)
│ ├config_r.php(644)
│ ├b.php(644)
│ ├p.php(644)
│ ├r.php(644)
│ ├index.txt(644)
│ ├form.txt(644)
│ ├caps.cgi(666)
│ ├headad.txt(666)
│ ├putad.txt(666)
│ ├option.txt(666)
│ └omikuji(755)/┬omikuji.txt(644)
│ ├base.txt(644)
│ ├who.txt(644)
│ ├where.txt(644)
│ ├do.txt(644)
│ └food.txt(644)
│
├2ch.gif(644)
├ba.gif(644)
│
└board(755)/┬dat(777)/
├html(777)/
├kako(777)/┬index.php(644)
│ └kako.txt(666)
├i(755)/─index.html(666)
├img(777)/
├img2(777)/
├0thello(777)/
├SETTING.TXT(666)
├config.php(666)
├subject.txt(666)
├subback.html(666)
├index.html(666)
├head.txt(666)
├RIP.cgi(666)
├timecheck.cgi(666)
├hostlog.cgi(666)
├uerror.cgi(666)
└threadconf.cgi(666)
```

Comment: 「`phpファイルをhtmlで読み込ませたい`」の意味がよく分かりません。また、ご自身で何をしたか、どういった動作が想定のもので、こういった想定外の動作をした。などを記載するとより回答者に問題点が伝わりやすくなるかと思います。再現にコードが必要であれば、PHPファイルのソースコードもサンプルとして展開したほうが良いかと思います。……もしかしてとは思いますが「`htmlファイルをphpで読み込ませたい`」訳ではありませんよね？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。分かりづらくて申し訳ありません。あと、自分が知りたかったのはphp ファイルをどこにアップロードすれば動作するのかということです。

Answer (score 1):

エックスサーバーの[マニュアルページ](https://www.xserver.ne.jp/manual/index.php)をよく確認してください。

CGIの設置場所に関しては「どこでも可」とされています(一般的には`cgi-bin`以下などに指定されている場合がありますが)。
https://www.xserver.ne.jp/manual/man_program_cgi.php

「PHPファイルをHTMLで読み込ませたい」が「**拡張子がhtmlのPHPファイルもCGIとして動作させたい**」であるなら、`.htaccesss`ファイルの編集を行うのが一般的かと思います。
https://www.xserver.ne.jp/manual/man_server_htaccess.php

**.htaccesss**

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html
```

---

[追記]
PHPなどを**CGIのプログラムとして動作させる**には、HTMLや画像のように単にアップロードしただけではダメで実行権限を付けてあげる必要があります。
質問文に載せられたファイル一覧ではファイルのアクセス権限がすべて`644`となっていますが、エックスサーバーでの仕様は先述したマニュアルページに以下の記載があります。

> CGIファイルのパーミッション: 755, 705 のいずれか

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。

Comment: あと、ファイルをサーバーのFTP にアップロードして、そのうち一つのファイルにブラウザ(Internet Explore)からアクセスしようとすると、ダウンロードの表示と追跡という画面が出てきて、そこから「ファイルを開く」を押しても開けません。どうしたら開けますか？

Comment: Visual Studio Codeに関する質問でもそうでしたが、単に「開けません」では『どんな動作を期待しているのか』が分かりません（何で開ければよいのか？）。phpをプログラムとして動作させたいのであれば、実行権限（パーミッション）の設定が適切でないように見えます。ファイル一覧で`*.php`ファイルも`644`になっていますが、ヘルプページにもある通り`755`にする必要があります。